# Force avcodec_receive_packet to return packet

Tags: ffmpeg

There are related answers but they do not answer my question.
I am encoding intra only mpeg1video using FFmpeg api and I would like to get packets out of the encoder without delay starting from the very first frame, but I get AVERROR(EAGAIN) from avcodec_receive_packet.
I read this:

> At the beginning of decoding or encoding, the codec might accept
> multiple input frames/packets without returning a frame, until its
> internal buffers are filled

Is there a way to remedy this e.g. may be by changing internal buffer size ?

Answer (score 0):

With libx264 encoder, try setting small value for `rc-lookahead`, `keyint/min-keyint` or `vbv-bufsize`. Eg: setting `rc-lookahead=5` to make encoder to expect only 5 frames before outputting the first encoded packet. Note that this might increase encoded packet's size.

Hope you find similar options with mpeg1video encoder.